# Remove datagridviewcomboboxcell from 1 specific cell in a datagridviewcomboboxcollumn

Tags: c#, forms, datagridview

I have an datagridview as shown in image 1 the row at the bottom does have 2 comboboxcell as expected because I set that collumn to that type. But i want to change that comboboxcell to an textboxcell but the other cells in that collumn needs to stay a comboboxcell.
In the rows underneath klant and project, there are values except for the last row. this row needs to show the total of al the rows

Image[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yMlY1.png)

I hope someone can help me out i can't find anything on google and here on stackoverflow.

Comment: I found out nog that if I change the readonly of a specific row it will also change the readonly for all the other cells in the same collumn.

Comment: This behaviour as described above is applied because of [DataGridViewBand](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.datagridviewband.aspx)

Comment: It seems it can't be done by setting the readonly, it needs to be done like told in [this link](http://www.dotnetmonster.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/winform-controls/4469/Set-readonly-property-on-cell-level-in-a-datagridview)

Answer (score 1):

You can set individual cells of a datagridview:

```
DataGridViewCell newCell = new DataGridViewTextBoxCell();
// Set more properties here.
dataGridView1[row, column] = newCell;
```

Comment: unfortunatly that won't work it will not only change that specific cell, it changes the entire collumn to datagridviewtextboxcell.